# When i select an option for a dropdown list,this affectes all the other dropdown lists value

Tags: html, .net, angular, frontend, dropdown

[image: Problem]

Here is my dropdown lists for rows.And these dropdown lists created with ngFor.When i select an option for any dropdown list, the selected value of all dropdowns change.Can anyone help me for this.

[image: Codes]

And this is my code.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume, given that this is just images instead of posted html/ts code, that the issue lies in your ngModel for the select option. You are using the same model for all of them, thus any change would of course be reflected throughout all of the elements that use that model.

What you need to do is define a model for each one of those dropdown

Comment: Yes but I could not figure out how to do that.I use the index of first ngFor but then how can i access the selected option and pass it through the buttons click function?

Comment: So you already have the index in our outer loop. You can pass it into your on change method.

Answer (score 0):

your `ngModel selectedStudent` is the same for all the dropdowns. If the value changes, it will impact all the dropdowns